# dictionary using in python creating a movie cinema

Tags: python, computer-science

The dictionary will store the names of the movies, and for each movie the dictionary value will be a list of show times.

I could not figure it out. Is that correct???

```
movie A: 9,11,15 movie B: 10,14,6 movie C: 11,13,19

dictionary={"moviesA":0, "moviesB":0, "moviesC":0}

showingtimes={"moviesA": 9, "moviesA": 11, "moviesA": 15, "moviesA": 21, "moviesB" : 10, "moviesB": 14, "moviesB": 16,
              "moviesC": 11, "moviesC":13, "moviesC":19, "moviesC": 20, "moviesC": 21, "movieC":22}
```

Comment: Did you understand the key on dict type which is can't be duplication!

Comment: yes, i was just doing both.Trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store it like :

```
data1={'movie A': [9,11,15], 'movie B': [10,14,6], 'movie C': [11,13,19]}
```

Now if you want to check by time you can do :

```
#which movies shows available at 11 ?

def check_by_time(time_mo):
    movies_list=[]
    for i, j in data1.items():
        if time_mo in j:
            movies_list.append(i)
    return movies_list
print(check_by_time(11))
```

output:

```
['movie A', 'movie C']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `list` to store your showtimes. The `key` of your dictionary will be the name of the movie, and its `value` is the list of showtimes.

```
d["movieA"] = [9, 11, 13, 15]
d["movieB"] = [13, 17]
```